# ServiceStack : How to catch errors before written to response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, servicestack

I develop a Rest Service by using ServiceStack. 
My model contains a DateTime property and the problem start with it.If a client post/get wrong formatted date value as string , ServiceStack fires an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles) +6364458
   ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeBuiltin`1.<GetParseFn>b__b(String value) in C:\src\ServiceStack.Text\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeBuiltin.cs:58
   ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\ServiceModel\Serialization\StringMapTypeDeserializer.cs:79

[SerializationException: KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\ServiceModel\Serialization\StringMapTypeDeserializer.cs:95
   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RestPath.CreateRequest(String pathInfo, Dictionary`2 queryStringAndFormData, Object fromInstance) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\ServiceHost\RestPath.cs:319
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\RestHandler.cs:104
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\RestHandler.cs:80
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +625
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
```

I know its an error and I know it must be catches but I want to implement it with my error codes and error descriptions(human friendly).

Any advice could be very helpful about how to catch an exception before its written to response itself on (DebeugMode=true) or the service fires an exception to client.

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your Custom Request Binder (or more advanced option is to implement IRequiresRequestStream on your DTOs) to by-pass ServiceStack's deserialization with your own.

More information about this is contained in [ServiceStack's wiki documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization)

Comment: Thnx for your reply.It worked properly.It could be very handy to achieve similar thing just by overriding HandleException virtual method when my service class inherited from ServiceBase or RestServiceBase.